# Multiple Jenkins webhooks on single Bitbucket repo

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket

Is it possible to set up multiple jenkins endpoint on a single bitbucket repo?
I am checking around the UI on bitbucket, and it seems only one end point is allowed.

I have three machines. One is for development purpose where other users will be contributing to it and the build will trigger after dev branch is updated for testing and verification. The other two will be production machines behind a nginx loader balancer, where the trigger will be the master branch.

If a only a single endpoint is allowed, what would be a better approach to this case?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Regards

Comment: Have you found any solution for this case? I also have this issue and haven't found anything.